# How to Add an Array as an Item in Another Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Imagine that I have create an array as follows:

```
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

I now want to create another array like this:

```
var arr2 = [arr1, 'four', 'five']
```

This is now the contents of arr2:

```
[Array(3), "four", "five"]
```

That is NOT what I want.  I would like the contents to look like this:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

How can I do that?

Note, I'm **not** looking for a function like concat, but rather a way to list arr1 as an item in arr2 in such a way that all the items in arr1 will be added as individual items in arr2 (I hope that made sense).

Thanks for any help that you can offer.

Comment: "Note, I'm not looking for a function like concat, but rather a way to list arr1 as an item in arr2 in such a way that all the items in arr1 will be added as individual items in arr2 (I hope that made sense)." -> then you do want concat... Concat merges the arrays. The second snippet in your post adds the array as an item in the array. You can't do both.

Comment: Using ES2015/ES6 -> `arr2 = [...arr1, 'four', 'five']`

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans concat will return a new array. They want to put the items into arr2 and not create a new array.

Comment: @George ah, thank you for the clarification. It's getting late.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...` you can do exactly that.

> The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment) are expected.

```js
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var arr2 = [...arr1, 'four', 'five']

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: @Nenad Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there an advantage of using this over [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift?v=control)?

Comment: @George if you just use `unshift` like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1922/ it will add whole array and not each element, but if you use it with spread syntax like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1923/ then why use `unshift`

Comment: @NenadVracar well if you use unshift like in the example it gives you on the documentation you've linked in your answer [it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1924/). I was just wondering if there was any benefit to using the spread operator over unshift aka speed/compatibility etc

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: Now the question is changed, this solution no long supplies the question.**

You can use concat for this:

```
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var arr2 = arr1.concat(['four', 'five', 'six']);
```

Which outputs

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using new versions of JS. You may do it just like this:

```
var
  array1 = [1,2,3],
  array2 = [3, 4, 5];

  array2.unshift(...array1);

  // array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  // array1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ways to achieve this :**

**1. ES6 [Array.of()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of?v=control) method :** It will create a new Array with a variable number of arguments, regardless of number or type of the arguments.

```js
const arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const arr2 = Array.of(...arr1, 'four', 'five');

console.log(arr2);
```

**2. Using [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=control) method :** This method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

```js
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

var arr2 = arr1.concat(['four', 'five']);

console.log(arr2);
```

**3. Using ES6 [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control) method :** It also creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

```js
const arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

Array.from(['four', 'five'], item => arr1.push(item));

console.log(arr1);
```